# How to execute output of SQL UDF using Javascript stored procedure in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I created a UDF that takes 4 parameters and outputs a DDL statement

```
select * from table(my_udf('some_text',some_integer,some_integer,'some_text''));
```

Here is one sample of a DDL statement the SQL UDF outputs as a table with one row

```
create or replace temporary view some_view as

select * from some_table1 union all
select * from some_table2;
```

How can I create a Javascript based procedure that basically takes the same parameters as my SQL UDF and executes the DDL statement. I am not so familiar with Javascript, which is why I left all the heavy lifting to SQL so I could keep the stored procedure as simple as possible in case I need to replicate it for a different use case.

This is my attempt so far based on the examples I came across. There is probably a lot wrong my code, but if someone could point me in the right direction, that'd be huge

```
create or replace temporary procedure jvs_udf(PAR_1 varchar, PAR_2 number, PAR_3 number, ARG_4 varchar)
returns string not null
language Javascript
as

$$
sql_command = 'select * from table(my_udf(' + PAR_1 + ',' + PAR_2 + ',' + PAR_3 + ',' + PAR_4 + '))' ;
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: sql_command}).execute();
return --how do I also get it to return the message I would have gotten had I run DDL in UI?
$$;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reuse your table UDF and pass parameters using [binds](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#binding-variables):

```
create or replace temporary procedure jvs_udf(PAR_1 varchar, PAR_2 varchar, 
                                              PAR_3 varchar, ARG_4 varchar)
returns string not null
language Javascript
as
$$
sql_command = 'select * from table(my_udf(:1, :2, :3, :4))';
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: sql_command
                                     ,binds: [PAR1, PAR2, PAR3, ARG4]}).execute();

stmt.next();
var ddl_statement = stmt.getColumnValue(1);

snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: ddl_statement}).execute();

return 'View created';
$$;
```

Comment: The thing is `create or replace view view_name` is included in the output of the SQL UDF. View name changes per the parameters. I am also getting `Language JAVASCRIPT does not support type 'NUMBER(38,0)' for argument or return type` error

Comment: @Rajat Then you need to get the output of first call and execute it. Please see my update

Comment: Any way around that number data type error?

Comment: @Rajat You could use FLOAT instead of NUMBER.

Comment: hmm stored proc got created but got this error on `call jvs_udf('some_test',some_num,some_num,'some_test')`

`Execution error in store procedure EXECUTE_STACK: SQL execution internal error: Processing aborted due to error 300002:2326015038; incident 2768663. At Statement.execute, line 3 position 122`

Comment: You need to start debuging it(it is out of scope of this question). I suggest checking if the generated code works by running manually. Then I would check the permissions, if objects are in correct schema etc.

Comment: Okay, will do. I'll accept this answer because I got the template I was looking for

Comment: Figured it out. Had to do with data types. Set everything to varchar and handled data conversion in the SQL UDF. Working as expected now

Comment: @Rajat That's great :)

Answer (score 0):

It later occurred to me that I could have simply passed my select statement as parameter to the stored proc.

```
create or replace procedure jvs_udf(SQL_COMMAND varchar)
returns string not null
language Javascript
execute as caller
as
$$
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: SQL_COMMAND}).execute();
stmt.next();
var ddl = stmt.getColumnValue(1);
return ddl;
$$;
```

Usage would then look like

```
call jvs_udf(select * from table(my_udf('some_text',some_integer,some_integer,'some_text')));
```